Renormalization and 1PI effective potential (Coleman-Weinberg)
I have a question regarding deriving the 1PI effective potential up to the 1-loop level of the $\phi^4$ renormalized theory. What I did is to renormalize the theory as follows:
$$
\mathcal{L}(\phi)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_\mu \phi_B\right)\left(\partial^\mu \phi_B\right)-\frac{1}{2} m_B^2 \phi_B^2-\frac{\lambda_B}{4!} \phi_B^4 .
$$
and we write the bare quantities as,
$$
\phi_B=\sqrt{Z} \phi, \quad m_B^2 Z=m^2+\delta m^2, \quad \lambda_B Z^2=Z_\lambda \lambda.
$$
Therefore the lagrangian becomes:
$$
L(\phi)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_\mu \phi\right)\left(\partial^\mu \phi\right)-\frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2-\frac{\lambda}{4!} \phi^4 + \frac{1}{2}(Z-1)\left(\partial_\mu \phi\right)\left(\partial^\mu \phi\right)-\frac{1}{2} \delta m^2 \phi^2-\frac{\lambda}{4!}\left(Z_\lambda-1\right) \phi^4.
$$
Now we write the field as $\phi \rightarrow \phi_0 + \phi$ where $\phi_0$ is the classical background and $\phi$ the quantum fluctuation. And then we do the 1PI path integral up to one loop over the field $\phi$, therefore I discard all the terms linear in $\phi$ as well as the cubic and quartic ones. By doing this the counter term part of the lagrangian reads as,
$$
L_{counterterm} = \frac{1}{2}(Z-1)\left(\partial_\mu \phi\right)\left(\partial^\mu \phi\right)-\frac{1}{2} \delta m^2 (\phi_0 + \phi)^2-\frac{\lambda}{4!}\left(Z_\lambda-1\right) (\phi_0 + \phi)^4
$$
Where the classical background is static. Here there is my question: Obviously I'm discarding linear cubic and quartic term in the counterterm lagrangian (since I'm just looking for 1PI up to one loop) but the term proportional to $\phi^2$ should be discarded or not? (The answer should be yes so we have just the couterterm for $\phi_0$ but I can't see why we should discard them.)

Remember that counter terms are there to cancel divergence of loop integrals.  They count as at least 1-loop by themselves.  If you have a counter term incorporated into a 1-loop Feynman diagram, it is at least 2-loop.  So you don't see any of these in an 1-loop calculation.
